# getElement for class?

Tags: javascript, class, button

I want to make this works with class, instead of id:

```
function su() {
    var x = document.getElementById("dh");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}

<button onclick="su()" class="sh"></button>
<div class="dh">
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `querySelector(".dh")` instead of `document.getElementById("dh")` to target the first element with the class `dh`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use for loop.

Also, consider using meaningful names for your classes

```
   const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('dh');
    
    function su(){
      for(let i =0; i< elements.length; i++){
        const x = elements[i];
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```